# How to manage several VPNs for customers?

Tags: vpn, virtualization

This is, somehow, a theoretical question.

I am working in a software-developer company. We have several customers. For each customer we have a Virtual Machine where we have a VPN to the customer installed.

At the moment we have too much VMs and the administrative work to keep them up to date is really high.

It doesn't make sense to install all those various VPN-Clients to every PC of every developer, so we introduced VMs years ago. VMs are really nice, because you can access the developement environment really quick. But now the number of VMs has grown too big.

**EDIT 1**: We already deploy updates automatically with Windows Update Services and we have a Master-Template for new Virtual Machines which is up to date.

**EDIT 2**: At the moment there are over 100 VMs. The number is growing continiously and our ESX-Host has no more capacity. There are about 30 VMs which run simultaniously.

Now the question: How can we get rid of the VMs but connect anyway to our Customer-VPNs?

One additional note: The company is located in Europe. Due to a new law it will be difficult to establish a site-to-site-vpn (General Data Protection Regulation - GDPR)

**EDIT 3**: The GDPR does not allow a permanent access to private data from other companies. The access has to be build up manually

Maybe there is a tool or something where you can manage and set-up different VPNs in a fast and easy way?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Replace all those with a network device VPN (ASA or router VPN).

Comment: *At the moment we have too much VMs and the administrative work to keep them up to date is really high*. I do not understand. Modern OS allow for automatic updates, and a VM hosting only a client VPN should not that complex. In additions, systems like [puppet](https://puppet.com) allow to automatically spread config changes to multiple (virtual) machines.

Comment: Why would GDPR makes it difficult for your company to setup site to site VPN?

Comment: @Overmind: What is "ASA"? And could you give me further details? I think I didn't get you right now.

Comment: It's the new generation of firewalls from CISCO, which all support relatively easy to setup VPN, to which you can use access lists to control accesses instead of isolated VMs.

Comment: The strange thing in your situation here is that why does your developers have access to personal data at all? Companies that runs with over 100 developers is large enough that you should isolate most developers from having access to production systems, so that only operations personnels and possibly a few senior developers should be given access to production systems. The rest should only have access to test data.

Comment: @LieRyan It is not productive data. We have partners which host their own test-systems and these we need to access.